# Is it allowed to pass paths as URLs to Media Foundation?

Tags: windows, winapi, ms-media-foundation

Passing standard Windows file paths like `C:\Foo\Bar.mp4` to methods like `IMFSourceResolver::CreateObjectFromURL()` works fine here but I'm wondering if this is allowed because, strictly speaking, `C:\Foo\Bar.mp4` is not a URL. It would probably have to be translated into something like `file:///C:/Foo/Bar.mp4` in order to qualify as a URL.

Still, for simplicity's sake, I'm wondering if simply passing a path name is ok as well or is this something that just happens to work but should rather be avoided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm wondering if simply passing a path name is ok as well or is this
> something that just happens to work but should rather be avoided?

No, this is not an accident.

From [IMFSourceResolver::CreateObjectFromURL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfidl/nf-mfidl-imfsourceresolver-createobjectfromurl#remarks),

**For local files, you can pass the file name in the pwszURL parameter; the file: scheme is not required.**

Note : This method cannot be called remotely.